# No key defined error, even though Key attribute present

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm making a very simple MVC application to manage some household things. Before, I would always make my data models in MVC model generator (the GUI thing), or import already-made SQL tables.

This time, I wanted to do it with a code first approach.

I will hereby give you an example of an Entity:

```
 public class Expense {

    [Key]
    public int ExpenseId;

    public double ExpenseValue;
    public DateTime ExpenseDate;
    public string ExpenseDescription;

    public ExpenseType ExpenseType;
    public Currency ExpenseCurrency;

    public List<ExpenseUser> Users;

}
```

And my DbContext derived object:

```
public class HawsContext : DbContext {

    public DbSet<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ExpenseType> ExpenseTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ExpenseUser> ExpenseUsers { get; set; }

    public ExpenseUser GetUserByUserName(string userName) {
        return ExpenseUsers.Where(u => u.UserName == userName).FirstOrDefault();
    }

}
```

Any time I instantiate the object I receive the following error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Expense' has no
>   key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'ExpenseType' has
>   no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'ExpenseUser' has
>   no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet
>   'Expenses' is based on type 'Expense' that has no keys defined.
>   \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet
>   'ExpenseTypes' is based on type 'ExpenseType' that has no keys
>   defined. \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet
>   'ExpenseUsers' is based on type 'ExpenseUser' that has no keys
>   defined.

What am I doing wrong? All of my Entities have [Key] in front of their respective keys, everything gets compiled without error or warning. It only doesn't work once I instantiate the context, presumably when it is about to get created (it still hasn't actually created any SQL tables)

Comment: In your error all three objects seem to have this issue... it's not only Expense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I google search revealed the issue. You have to make your Key properties.

```
[Key]
public int ExpenseId {get; set;}
```

Comment: Thank you, the accessors were the culprits indeed.

Comment: It will only work, after adding the attribute [Key] and re-compile before adding the controller.